# Do you know of any good resources to support my research; or even of an application that exists already?

Tags: agile

I am thinking of developing software to facilitate home and small businesses in developing applications using the agile methodology.

Do you know of any good resources to support my research; or even of an application that exists already?

Comment: *"the agile methodology"*, there is no such thing.

Comment: Do you want to use agile methods for your project or is your project intended to help people create software using agile methods?

Comment: XP, Scrum, Crystal - even RUP claims to be "agile" if you choose appropriately from their grab bag of stuff.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. There are a number of project management packages for Agile - VersionOne, TFS templates, agilezen.com, etc. There are unit testing tools and continuous integration servers. You may want to be more specific.

Comment: Hi guys. I appreciate that this is a broad question, but I will try to narrow down the scope (having read comments and answers!).
The aim is (and not to tread on existing software, it would be free/open source if pursued) to build software that would help individuals and small teams through building software - e.g. recording customer requirements, following progress, allowing current sprint and future sprint to be separated and clarified etc. It would enable the flexibility of agile methods, being concise and fluid with the workload.

Comment: Having had time to investigage, a desktop version of AgileZen is exactly the sort of thing I was thinking about. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: I have started to prototype an application, available here: http://code.google.com/p/storyboard-agile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management) comes to mind as an example of such an application, though you may want to do some more digging to see if it is appropriate for your audience.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think agile methods are necessarily about software; they're more about describing the interactions of a team amongst themselves and with their customers.

If you Google "agile software" you'll see that there are a number of tools on the market already for estimating, tracking, managing, etc.  I don't know what you'll add over and above those.

There is some research about the value of agile methods, but I'm not sure how scientific any of it is.  The biggest problem you have when developing software in general is metrics: How do we measure productivity?  No one knows or agrees.  Any study will have to pretend that it knows.  Your work will have this problem as well.

Comment: I should add that I understand what you are saying and accept it. However, I was asking about finding/writing software that facilitates those interactions. You are spot on in your third paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

[Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/) is one of the first products I know of that comes to mind. Perhaps even Fogbugz too, though that tends to be more geared towards stricter time recording of tasks.

That's agile for management of projects.

Comment: Your answer is good, but I can only choose one. I will have to stick to the point in my question re small businesses; whereby the answer  referring to Mingle is slightly more appropriate as the software can be scaled in cost as well as performance to suit smaller teams and budgets.